# How to find $\lim _{x\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{x+3}{x+4}\right)^x$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I know the answer is 
$$
\lim _{x\to \infty \:}\ln\left(\frac{x+3}{x+4}\right)^x
=\lim _{x\to \infty \:}x\cdot\ln\left(\frac{x+3}{x+4}\right)
=\lim _{x\to \infty \:}\frac{\ln(x+3/x+4)}{1/x}=-1
$$

I know it has to do with L'Hopital rule, but I get the answer
$$
\lim _{x\to \infty \:}\frac{(x+4)/(x+3)}{-1/x^2},
$$
which is wrong.

Please help me.

Comment: You couldalso write it as $1-1/(x+4)$ to the power of $x$ and find the answer from there. Hopital shouldn’t be needed

Comment: i want know how to solve $ \lim _{x\to \infty \:}\frac{\ln(x+3/x+4)}{1/x}$ with L'Hopital rule

Comment: Oh, ok, I had thought the thing gimusi posted in its answer.

Comment: You could use Taylor expansion at first order of $\log(1+t)$, which is simpler. If you don't wish to do so, just derive that expression and see what you get, it should be polynomial, so no problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may not have differentiated $\log_e((x+3)/(x+4))$ correctly.  As the logarithm of the quotient is the difference between the individual logarithms, thus

$\log_e((x+3)/(x+4))=\log_e(x+3)-\log_e(x+4)$,

your numerator after applying l'H should be

$(1/(x+3))-(1/(x+4))$.

See where that gets you.

Comment: thank you very much! I didn't differentiate the logarithm of the quotient is the point of the problem .

Answer (score 9):

As an alternative

$$\left(\frac{x+3}{x+4}\right)^x=\left(\frac{x+4-1}{x+4}\right)^x=\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{x+4}\right)^{x+4}\right]^\frac{x}{x+4}$$

Comment: wonderful answer  thanks, but i want to know how to solve it with L'Hopital rule

Comment: It's easier to check your result if you know the correct answer.

Comment: @陈柯行 If not explicitly requested, l'Hopital rule should be avoided to solve limits when we can refer to **Standard limits**. Those are very important to get skilled and confident with the resolution.

Comment: @gimusi get it. I just begin to learn calculus, great answer, thank you.

Comment: @陈柯行 You are welcome! Search for standard limits and study in detail their proof: sin x/x, (e^x-1)/x, x logx, log(1+x)/x, etc.

Comment: Gimusi.Nice. It is just the double exponent(hm...)Greetings.

Answer (score 4):

Using *equivalents* is much simpler than L'Hospital's rule: you have to find the limit of
$$x\ln\frac{x+3}{x+4}\; \text{ at }\infty. $$
Now, $\;\ln(1+u)\sim_0 u$, so 
$$x\ln\frac{x+3}{x+4}=x\ln\Bigl(1-\frac{1}{x+4}\Bigr)\sim_{x\to\infty}-\frac x{x+4} \sim_{x\to\infty}-\frac xx=-1.$$

Answer (score 3):

$$ \left(\frac {x+3}{x+4}\right)^x = \left(1-\frac {1}{x+4}\right)^{(x+4)-4}\to e^{-1}$$

Comment: Shouldn't you multiply and divide by $x+4$? I think gimusi is right, for instance

Comment: @tommy1996q: this is fine apart from typo and only a bit simpler than gimusi's version. +1

Comment: Fixed typo in final answer.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh thanks for the correction.

Comment: Yeah I imagined it, but maybe the one asking the question could have misinterpreted the typo.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh It is of course an almost equivalent way to solve but I’m not sure it is simpler (for a not skilled solver) since to fully justify the final step we should add that $$\left(\frac {x+3}{x+4}\right)^x = \left(1-\frac {1}{x+4}\right)^{(x+4)-4}=\frac{\left(1-\frac {1}{x+4}\right)^{x+4}}{\left(1-\frac {1}{x+4}\right)^{4}}\to e^{-1}$$ since $\left(1-\frac {1}{x+4}\right)^{4}\to 1$ which is trivial for all of us but which should be added to complete the derivation.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Similarly the version I used could be write $$\left(\frac{x+3}{x+4}\right)^x=\left(\frac{x+4-1}{x+4}\right)^x=\left(1-\frac{1}{x+4}\right)^{x}$$ which is also equivalent and apparently simpler but in reality it is solely a solution without an intermediate step.

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani I’ve edited for the parentheses if you don’t mind. (+1)

Comment: @gimusi  Thanks for the edition.

Answer (score 3):

Set
$$
f(t)=\frac{1}{t}\ln\frac{3t+1}{4t+1}
$$
Since
$$
\left(\frac{x+3}{x+4}\right)^{\!x}=\exp(f(1/t))
$$
we can compute $\lim{t\to0}f(t)$ and if this exists and is $l$, the limit you're looking for is $e^l$.
Now
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\ln(3t+1)-\ln(4t+1)}{t}
$$
is the derivative at $0$ of the function $g(t)=\ln(3t+1)-\ln(4t+1)$; since
$$
g'(t)=\frac{3}{3t+1}-\frac{4}{4t+1}
$$
we have $g'(0)=3-4=-1$, so the limit you asked is $e^{-1}$.

Your method is very similar, but you got wrong the derivative of
$$
\ln\frac{x+3}{x+4}=\ln(x+3)-\ln(x+4)
$$
which is
$$
\frac{1}{x+3}-\frac{1}{x+4}=\frac{1}{(x+3)(x+4)}
$$
so you should have had
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\dfrac{1}{(x+3)(x+4)}}{-\dfrac{1}{x^2}}=
\lim_{x\to\infty}-\frac{x^2}{(x+3)(x+4)}=-1
$$

Answer (score 2):

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\left (\dfrac{x^x(1+3/x)^x}{x^x(1+4/x)^x}\right )=$

$\dfrac {\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}(1+3/x)^x}{\lim_{ x \rightarrow \infty}(1+4/x)^x}=\dfrac{e^3}{e^4}=e^{-1}.$

Note:

Let $a >0$.

$(1+a/x)^x= ((1+\dfrac{1}{(\frac{x}{a})})^{\frac{x}{a}})^a.$

$y:=x/a.$

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}(1+a/x)^x=$

$\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty}((1+1/y)^y)^a=e^a.$

Comment: As long as you have shown that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}(1+a/x)^x=a$.

Comment: marty.Thanks.Edited.

Comment: That’s also an interesting way to see that!

Answer (score 2):

$$ \lim \:_{x\to \:\infty \:}\left(\frac{x+3}{x+4}\right)^x\:$$
$$\lim \:_{x\to \:\infty \:}\:\:x\cdot ln\left(\frac{x+3}{x+4}\right)\:$$
$$ \lim \:_{x\to \:\infty \:}\:\:ln\left(\frac{x+3}{x+4}\right)\:\div \:\frac{1}{x}$$
 Now use L'Hopital's rule,
$$\lim \:_{x\to \:\infty \:}\:\:\frac{1}{\left(x+3\right)\left(x+4\right)}\:\div \:\frac{-1}{x^2}$$

$$ \lim \:_{x\to \:\infty \:}\:\:\frac{1}{\left(x+3\right)\left(x+4\right)} \cdot \:-x^2$$
$$\lim \:_{x\to \:\infty \:}\:\:\frac{-x^2}{x^2+7x+12}$$

Apply L'Hopital's rule again,
$$\lim _{x\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{-2x}{2x+7}\right)$$

and again,
$$\lim _{x\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{-2}{2}\right)=-1$$

Comment: nice done!thanks for your reply!

Comment: If we want or we are requested to use l’Hopital that’s fine for the first step but from this step $$\frac{-x^2}{x^2+7x+12}$$ we absolutely do not need it to see that the limit is $-1$ by $$\frac{-1}{1+7/x+12/x^2}$$ and absolutely we do no need it in the final step.

Comment: @gimusi the rule applies to the preceding step.